# recording issues using AS3 and Red5

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, red5

I am facing some issue in recording the users webcamera using an AS3 script and Red5 as streaming server. I tried to use the buffer to check if the client finished sending the packets to the server. but it doesn't work properly. I have two cases: if I don't use the buffer timer, I can see the Recordedfile.flv.ser keep growing but it takes a long time to generate the final .flv file. and in case using bufferLenght to check the buffer, once I stop recording it generate immediately the .flv file but only with some segments which mean that in the client side seems that BufferLenght its always 0. I tried so many examples and options whether on the client side or at the server side, but I still have the same problem: Broken FLV files.

PS: I am using Red5 1.0 installed in centOS.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 1.0 final, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 have a bug in their delayed write mechanism that leads to broken .flv files with stuck video and only sound. the .flv files contain only sound and 1 or 2 frames of video.

We have hit this issue many times and we've made a patch for Red5 1.0.2 that fixes it. [This patch has also been committed to the Red5 source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/commit/7e4253f577a88d50613900986a46e5a915859123) by the Red5 team. The next version of red5 will include it. Until then you can [download a patched Red5 1.0.2 from here](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/).